# How to post List<Data> in android using retrofit

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit

I need to insert Gender and Address using retrofit but when i tried to call the api to insert the data it gives me an error that the my class field are cannot be empty.

code implementation :

```
List<ClaimBindingModel> al = new ArrayList<>();

    ClaimBindingModel cbmGender = new ClaimBindingModel();
    cbmGender.setType("Gender");
    cbmGender.setValue(radioButton.getText().toString());

    ClaimBindingModel cbmAddress = new ClaimBindingModel("Address", Objects.requireNonNull(tiedtAddress.getText()).toString());

    al.add(cbmGender);
    al.add(cbmAddress);
```

retrofit:

```
@Headers({ "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8"})
@PUT("/api/accounts/user/{id}/assignclaims")
Call<ResponseBody> assignClaimsToUser(
        @Path("id") String id,
        @Body List<ClaimBindingModel> claimsToAssign);
```

It gives me this error

```
fail : error The request is invalid.
fail : error_description {"claimsToAssign[1].Value":["The Claim Value field is required."],"claimsToAssign[1].Type":["The Claim Type field is required."],"claimsToAssign[0].Type":["The Claim Type field is required."],"claimsToAssign[0].Value":["The Claim Value field is required."]}
```

Model class : [ClaimBindingModel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGAy2.png)

Comment: Post `ClaimBindingModel class`

Comment: add it to question, not to comment, and format it as code

Comment: never add images of code. Add it to the question as text and format it as code

Comment: that is the response from your server. Check it's documentation which names it require the fields to have. Now it looks like it says that field names are incorrect

Comment: ill use same fields name both android and in the API

Comment: i can get my data from  List<ClaimBindingModel> al = new ArrayList<>() using al.get(0).getType but it seem my API can't